# how to create triangle custom shape android

Tags: android, xml, android-vectordrawable

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">

    <group android:name="triableGroup">
        <path
            android:name="triangle"
            android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:pathData="m 0,0 l 100,0 -100,100 z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

I want to to create [this type of shape](http://drive.google.com/open?id=1kyOwLIYqcdcAmFKqcxQYpedwXarX3iSj). But i tired.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with vector drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:width="24dp"
 android:height="24dp"
 android:viewportWidth="24.0" 
 android:viewportHeight="24.0"> 
<path android:pathData="M0,0 L24,0 L0,24 z" 
android:strokeColor="@color/color" 
android:fillColor="@color/color"/> 
</vector>`
```

Comment: i want to this type of image https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kyOwLIYqcdcAmFKqcxQYpedwXarX3iSj

Answer (score 0):

You can use vector for triangle shape. Here is my code for triangle vector

**triangle.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:pathData="M0,12l0,12 11.5,-5.7c6.3,-3.2 11.5,-6 11.5,-6.3 0,-0.3 -5.2,-3.1 -11.5,-6.3l-11.5,-5.7 0,12z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000"
    android:fillColor="#000000"/>
```

Put above file in drawable folder.
Now in your xml use below code,

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivTriangle"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:background="@drawable/triangle" />
```

Comment: this  code is not working according to my problem drive.google.com/open?id=1kyOwLIYqcdcAmFKqcxQYpedwXarX3iSj

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for your type of triangle.

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <RelativeLayout
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"/>

     <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
         android:layout_margin="@dimen/_1sdp"
         app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
         app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_100sdp"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp">

     </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```